# How to set Driver Path and Driver Class Name for a Glue Connection using CloudFormation Template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I am using a JSON CloudFormation template to create a Glue Connection. I need to set the "Driver Path" and "Driver Class Name". It's easy to set these properties on the AWS Console, but I can't figure out how to set these properties in the CloudFormation template. I assume they are somehow specified in the `ConnectionProperties` but [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-connection-connectioninput.html#cfn-glue-connection-connectioninput-connectionproperties) does not specify the property names.

What I tried:

- Read documentation
- Searched online
- Asked Amazon Q
- Tried several educated guesses

Still no luck. Here is my latest attempt (based on an answer from Amazon Q):

```json
"GlueDatabaseConnection": {
  "Type": "AWS::Glue::Connection",
  "Properties": {
    "CatalogId": {
      "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
    },
    "ConnectionInput": {
      "Name": "my-connection-name",
      "ConnectionType": "JDBC",
      "ConnectionProperties": {
        "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "my-jdbc-url",
        "SECRET_ID": "my-secret-id",
        "JDBC_ENFORCE_SSL": "false",
        "JDBC_DRIVER_S3_PATH": "path-to-driver",
        "DRIVER": "org.postgresql.Driver"
      },
      "PhysicalConnectionRequirements": {
        "SubnetId": "my-subnet-id",
        "SecurityGroupIdList": [
          "my-security-group-id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct properties are `JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_URI` and `JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`.

Full example:

```json
"GlueDatabaseConnection": {
  "Type": "AWS::Glue::Connection",
  "Properties": {
    "CatalogId": {
      "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
    },
    "ConnectionInput": {
      "Name": "my-connection-name",
      "ConnectionType": "JDBC",
      "ConnectionProperties": {
        "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "my-jdbc-url",
        "SECRET_ID": "my-secret-id",
        "JDBC_ENFORCE_SSL": "false",
        "JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_URI": "path-to-driver",
        "JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME": "org.postgresql.Driver"
      },
      "PhysicalConnectionRequirements": {
        "SubnetId": "my-subnet-id",
        "SecurityGroupIdList": [
          "my-security-group-id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I figured this out by inspecting the HTTP request that is sent when I set these properties on the AWS web console.